# Relationships between Riemann Xi and Jacobi Theta functions

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, modular-forms

I asked ChatGPT about the relationship between the Riemann Xi function and the Jacobi theta functions. ChatGPT provided the following relation:

$\xi\left(\frac{1}{2} + it\right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \theta_3^4(0, e^{-\pi t^2}) - \theta_4^4(0, e^{-\pi t^2}) \right)$

In the above equation,  $\theta_3$ represents the third Jacobi theta function, while $\theta_4$ represents the fourth Jacobi theta function.

$\theta_3(0,\tau) = 1 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{i \pi n^2 \tau} $

$\theta_4(0,\tau) = 1 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{i \pi n^2 \tau} $

I'm not familiar with this formula. I'm curious to know whether it's a hallucination on ChatGPT's part or if it's a well-established result.

If it is a well-known and proven result, could someone provide a reference for it? I've searched online and also inquired with ChatGPT, but I couldn't find a reference.

Comment: The relation is wrong

Comment: Would the tag [tag:artificial-intelligence] work?

Comment: @TravorLZH, thank you for the comment. How can we tell that the relation is wrong ?

Comment: The right hand side is undefined when $t=0$, but $\xi(1/2)$ does have a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two notations for theta functions. They are related by

$$
\theta_j(z\vert\tau)=\theta_j(z,e^{\pi i\tau}),\tag1
$$

so it is more correct to write $\theta_j(z|\tau)$ instead of $\theta_j(z,\tau)$. From the identity

$$
\theta_3^4(0\vert\tau)=\theta_2^4(0\vert\tau)+\theta_4^4(0\vert\tau),
$$

we see that the OP's identity is equivalent to

$$
\xi\left(\frac12+it\right)=\frac12\theta_2^4(0,e^{-\pi t^2}).\tag2
$$

From the infinite product formula (with $q=e^{-\pi t^2}$)

$$
\theta_2(0,q)=2q^{1/4}\prod_{n\ge1}(1-q^{2n})(1+q^{2n})^2,
$$

it is clear that the right hand side has no zeros when $|q|<1$, which clearly contradicts the fact that $\xi\left(\frac12+it\right)$ has infinitely many real zeros (i.e. $\zeta$ has infinitely many zeros on the critical line).